# Rails simple_fields_for can't hide :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I've been using simple_form for rails together with HAML

I have a number of line_items they have a unique id which i retrieve from the Order object

```
    = f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |line_items|
     .f.input :id unless @order.status?
     .f.input :cost unless @order.status?
```

However, whenever i iterate through these list, i would like to hide (remove from the form) the line_items id, i try to put a unless statement to remove other parameters and it works (eg. :cost) but for the :id it appears to be a hidden fields

```
     <input id="order_line_items_attributes_2_id" name="order[line_items_attributes][2][id]" type="hidden" value="26">
```

How can i successfully remove IDs from appearing in the fields just like how i did it for :cost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

`= f.simple_fields_for :line_items, include_id: false do |line_items|`

more on this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Answer (score 0):

Rails thinks that you should NEVER need to edit the :id,  so it makes it difficult or impossible.    If you want to DISPLAY the :id,  that's fine,  but there would be limited reason to present the :id such that it can be edited.

I'd just always display the id in the form.

Comment: I'd require to filter the line_items, with line_items ID, my controller would take into consideration that this item is being included....

I'm trying to remove these ID's so that i would be able to filter the order list only accepting items that has been verified and accepted...

Comment: Imagine a case with a nested form that lives inside a `<table>`-Tag. In that case `= f.simple_fields_for` will render `<table><tr>...</tr><input type='hidden' ... /></table>` which is invalid html. In that case you'd want to use the solution pasted above. Another case would be to have composite primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

A work around...

I tricked the system, by rending the fields as i uses HTML comment to stop it from appearing and stopped it from being submitted

```
/ =f.input :id unless @order.status?
```

I uses = instead of - so as the fields would be able to be rendered however hiding inside the html comment

```
<!--<input class="hidden" id="order_line_items_attributes_2_product_id" name="order[line_items_attributes][2][product_id]" type="hidden" />-->
```